# Declare method to throw an exception and subclass of this exception

Tags: java, exception

Is it meaningful to declare a method to throw an exception
and a subclass of this exception,
e.g. *IOException* and *FileNotFoundException*?

I guess that it is used in order to handle both exceptions by a caller method differently.
However, is it possible to handle both exceptions if the method throws **only** the most generic i.e *IOException*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, is it possible to handle both exceptions if the method throws only the most generic i.e IOException?

Absolutely. You can still *catch* them separately:

```
try {
  methodThrowingIOException();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  doSomething();
} catch (IOException e) {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

So it makes no difference to what the caller *can* do if the method declares both - it's redundant. However, it can *emphasize* exceptions that you might want to consider. This could be done better in Javadoc than just the throws declaration.

Comment: Why is Javadoc better than code? Usually code is preferable to comments, are exceptions an exception?

Comment: @Mark: It's not *instead* of code. It's *as well as* the throws declaration. But you need the throws declaration in order to document the specific exceptions (IIRC). The point is that *just* using a throws declaration doesn't allow you to give any explanation - whereas javadoc does.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it meaningful to declare a method to throw an exception and a subclass of this exception, e.g. IOException and FileNotFoundException?

Usually not - most IDEs I know of even issue warnings for such declarations. What you can and should do is to document the different exceptions thrown in Javadoc.

> However, is it possible to handle both exceptions if the method throws only the most generic i.e IOException?

Yes it is, you just need to ensure that the catch blocks are in the right order, i.e. more specific first. Catch blocks are evaluated in the order they are defined, so here

```
try {
  ...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
```

if the exception thrown is a `FileNotFoundException`, it will be caught by the first `catch` block, otherwise it will fall to the second and dealt with as a general `IOException`. The opposite order would not work as `catch (IOException e)` would catch all `IOException`s including `FileNotFoundException`. (In fact, the latter would result in a compilation error IIRC.)

Answer (score 0):

> However, is it possible to handle both exceptions if the method throws only the most generic i.e >IOException?

```
catch(IOException ex){
 if(ex instanceof FileNotFoundException){}
}
```

But this doesn't look clean, Throwing both exception looks good, even caller would come to know to that this method may throw these these exceptions, so they will handle it properly

Comment: You're right it's not clean - but it's not necessary, either. See my answer and Karthik's. Basically there's no need to have this ugliness.

Comment: @Jon if we declare method to throw IOException, how would caller come to know that it can also raise FileNotFoundException ?

Comment: It's not "also" - a FileNotFoundException *is* an IOException, so you can always try to catch it if the method declares that it throws IOException. It would be up to documentation to specify under what circumstances that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to handle both if the method only throws IOException.

The best way to answer such a question is to write a test to demonstrate it and try it out.  Let the JVM tell you the answer.  It'll be faster than asking here.

Comment: Actually the replies were quite fast and faster than it takes me to write a test class. My question had also another part and I hope it might be useful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

yes. when certain specialized exceptions can be handled correct. It is, if you handle the exceptions as follow:

```
try {
} catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
//Try a different file
} catch (IOException ioe) {
//Fatal, Maybe bad blocks ... Bail out... 
} catch (Exception e) {
//Something went wrong, see what it is...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring, that the method may throw (more *generic*) `IOException`, and (more *specific*) `FileNotFoundException` is usually a good thing - it's an additional information for people using your code later. Note that you should explicitely state in the JavaDoc, under what circumstances is each of the exceptions thrown.

They will still be able to distinguish the exceptions, and handle them differently using catch constructs like this one:

```
try {
    yourAwesomeMethod()
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // handle file-not-found error
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // handle other IO errors
}
```