# When throwing an exception from a java method, will a more general one override a more specific one?

Tags: java, exception, throws

The exact Error is: "There is a more general exception, 'java.lang.exception' in the throws list already"

I have a method like so:

```
public String myMethod() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        try{  
            // DO STUFF

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            // DO STUFF  
          throw new FileNotFoundException("custom message", e);

        }catch(IOException e){
          // DO STUFF
          throw new IOException("custom message", e); 

        }catch(Exception e){
          throw new Exception("custom message", e); 
        }
        return myString;
}
```

Intellij tells me that the first two are redundant because I have the more general `Exception` at the end, is that the case?
Will the method throw an `Exception` even if I explicitly throw an `IOException`?
Or is it the case that generic Exceptions will be thrown up the stack anyway, so I don't even need `Exception` on the end ?

Comment: your question makes no sense. This is the first-come, first-served principle. Only one Exception can be throwed at the time. No, the new Exception("", e) will not be thrown if you have an IOException, it will be if you don't catch IOException specifically and your code throws one

Comment: "they're not always reliable"?? what do you mean by that? They are quite reliable, do you really think an IDE could grow out to be one of the most used in a professional environment (especially if you have to pay to get all the functionalities) if it's not reliable? A better question here is: why do you use IntelliJ if you don't trust it to be reliable?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes I know that. But the linter says, as best I can tell, that because I have `Exception` in the `throws` part and that's more general than `IOException` then I should remove `IOException` from the `throws` at the top. But I don't want to have to check which type of exception it is further up the stack, I'd rather just throw the correct one from here..

Comment: @Stultuske not reliable is wrong, that was a bad phrase, I'll remove it.

Comment: So the issue is that intellij prompts me to throw a more general exception when I don't want to. It's not always best to declare a method throws only the most general case, when internally the actual exception thrown is more specific. It's not transparent to the caller if you do it that way. That's my issue with the linter in this case.

Comment: @bot_bot Your question is a little confusing for future readers: it looks like there is no clear reason why you *catch* the specified exceptions and then *rethrow* them to the caller.

Comment: Yes, I can see that.  I suppose one use case is where the issue need to be handled immediately here, but there are other places up the stack that need it too. For example, I'd rather throw the exception up the stack to a message publisher that can notify other services of the issue instead of having a message publisher in every lower level class to handle such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ does tell you that the second catch block is *never* reached. `FileNotFoundException` is a subtype of `IOException`, so if such exception occurs, then **the first** catch block is executed, since `IOException` matches the `FileNotFoundException` being thrown.

The catch blocks are always evaluated **in the order in which they are declared**. That means that if you swap the two catch blocks, it'll work.

#### Update

According to your comment, it is not the `try-catch` blocks IntelliJ notices you about, but the `throws` clause.

That is because for [*checked exceptions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1), Java forces you to declare them to be thrown in the method declaration. It is only necessary for the *most general* exception to be declared in the `throws` clause. The IDE is saying that because you declared `Exception` to be thrown, there is no need to also declare any subclass of `Exception`, since those cases are already covered by `Exception`.

However, the reasons you might still want to do that, is to provide more information to the caller. See [this question and answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/332466/why-throw-exception-that-is-subclass-of-another-exception-also-thrown) on Software Engineering StackExchange.

#### More information:

- [Declare method to throw an exception and subclass of this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116853/declare-method-to-throw-an-exception-and-subclass-of-this-exception)

---

I strongly discourage you to catch a too general exception. It's often a code smell.

- [Is it really that bad to catch a general exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938/is-it-really-that-bad-to-catch-a-general-exception)

Comment: My apologies, I wrote the example wrong, my code is correct. I've fixed it now. The linter says the following:  "There is a more general exception, 'java.lang.exception' in the throws list already"  And the `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException` at the top are grayed out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just been testing myself, and It appears that if I throw and `IOException` in a method that throws `Exception` I can still catch an `IOException` without having to check what it is first. I'll take a look Software Engineering StackExchange.   And yes, this was my concern when I asked this question. I'd rather throw/catch the specific exception where possible, and was wondering if I could catch an `IOException` if the method definition says `throws Exception` only. It appears I can.

Comment: But the issue then is others cannot see that I specifically throw `IOException` without going into my code to look.

Comment: @bot_bot That's where Javadoc kicks in: you should document *what* your method is supposed to do, what it expects and how it handles exceptions.